# Add a sheet with dynamic Sheet name in Excel as DATE

Tags: excel, vba

I use this code to create a new sheet with a dynamic name based on the real-time but it is not successful run, show

> error 1004 "application-defined or object-defined error".

```
Private Sub Compute_Click()

    With ThisWorkbook
    Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").Value = Now
    If IsDate(Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")) Then
        Set Worksheet = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))

       Worksheet.Name = Format(Range("A1"), "MM-DD-YYYY hh-mm-ss")

    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

- Use something other than `Worksheet` as your variable.
- You haven't specified which worksheet `Range("A1")` is on. That means there's an implicit `ActiveSheet`, which may not be (is not) the `Data` sheet.
- `Now` is a date so the `IsDate` check is unnecessary.

All that said, your revised code might look something like this:

```
Private Sub Compute_Click()
    With ThisWorkbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))

        ws.Name = Format(Now, "MM-DD-YYYY hh-mm-ss")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It's great now. Thank you so much.